# Unity2D How do i get the main camera to move up on the Y axis continuously after i left mouse click?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get my main camera to move upwards on the Y axis slowly only after the left mouse button is clicked.

Here is my code so far.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class CameraPanUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public Transform target;

    Vector3 offset;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    offset = transform.position - target.position;
}


// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 targetCamPos = target.position + offset;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetCamPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {

    }
}
```

}

I'm unsure what to put in the if statement above. I tried using transform.Translate before and it just made the Camera move up in small increments every time i left click. Why is that? Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: change it to `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` the camera will move up as long as mouse button is clicked and held down

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Coroutines:

```
Coroutine moveCoroutine;
IEnumerator StartMovingUp() {
  float moveSpeed = 2f;
  while(true) {
    transform.Translate(0, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    yield return null;
  }
}
void Update() {
  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && moveCoroutine == null) {
    moveCoroutine = StartCoroutine(StartMovingUp());
  }
}
```

another is doing it in the `Update` function with fields for state. Anything more may make the code too complicated.

```
bool isMovingUp;
float moveSpeed = 2f;
void Update() {
  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
    isMovingUp = true;
  }
  if (isMovingUp) {
    transform.Translate(0, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
  }
}
```